# Calcular percentual de um item em um grupo por ano no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho um `DF` com 14 colunas: `item`, `grupo` e anos de 2010 a 2021. Eu necessito saber o percentual de cada `item` dentro do `grupo` ao qual ele faz parte. Tentei utilizar um `group_by` com o `summarise`, mas como preciso do cálculo para cada um dos anos, não deu certo.

Tentei usar um `mutate_at`, mas também não deu certo.

Meu `dput`:

```
structure(list(Item = c("Carvão mineral", "Minerais não-metálicos", 
"Petróleo, gás natural e serviços de apoio", "Minério de ferro", 
"Minerais metálicos não-ferrosos", "Carne de bovinos e outros prod. de carne", 
"Carne de suíno", "Carne de aves", "Pescado industrializado", 
"Leite resfriado, esterilizado e pasteurizado", "Outros produtos do laticínio", 
"Açúcar", "Conservas de frutas, legumes, outros vegetais e sucos de frutas", 
"Óleos e gorduras vegetais e animais", "Café beneficiado", 
"Arroz beneficiado e produtos derivados do arroz", "Produtos derivados do trigo, mandioca ou milho", 
"Rações balanceadas para animais", "Outros produtos alimentares", 
"Bebidas", "Produtos do fumo", "Fios e fibras têxteis beneficiadas", 
"Tecidos", "Art. têxteis de uso doméstico e outros têxteis", 
"Artigos do vestuário e acessórios", "Calçados e artefatos de couro", 
"Produtos de madeira, exclusive móveis", "Celulose", "Papel, papelão, embalagens e artefatos de papel", 
"Serviços de impressão e reprodução"), Atividade = c("Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás", 
"Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás", "Combustíveis e lubrificantes básicos", 
"Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás", "Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás", 
"3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", "3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", 
"3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", "3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", 
"3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", "3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", 
"3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", "3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", 
"3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", "3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", 
"3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", "3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", 
"3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", "3.10 Fabricação de produtos alimentícios", 
"3.11 Fabricação de bebidas", "3.12 Fabricação de produtos do fumo", 
"3.13 Fabricação de produtos têxteis", "3.13 Fabricação de produtos têxteis", 
"3.13 Fabricação de produtos têxteis", "3.14 Confecção de artigos do vestuário e acessórios", 
"3.15 Preparação de couros e fabricação de artefatos de couro, artigos para viagem e calçados", 
"3.16 Fabricação de produtos de madeira", "3.17 Fabricação de celulose, papel e produtos de papel", 
"3.17 Fabricação de celulose, papel e produtos de papel", "3.18 Impressão e reprodução de gravações"
), `2010` = c(0, 3800, 0, 5705, 1540, 15471, 1203, 4387, 909, 
2045, 5336, 4713, 5285, 3850, 2291, 3668, 5273, 3974, 23901, 
14037, 1459, 1110, 2513, 6913, 27945, 10840, 4671, 1059, 9586, 
5218), `2011` = c(0, 4514, 0, 7229, 2054, 14430, 1048, 3753, 
861, 2644, 7965, 5350, 5701, 3700, 2356, 3645, 5988, 4355, 26759, 
12830, 1754, 2102, 4234, 8279, 33938, 12963, 5309, 1145, 11274, 
6862), `2012` = c(0, 3846, 0, 6400, 2316, 21339, 1195, 5872, 
1098, 2727, 8653, 5985, 6920, 5022, 2870, 4973, 7719, 5868, 29907, 
15592, 1965, 2095, 4347, 10057, 39308, 14406, 6012, 967, 14133, 
8790), `2013` = c(0, 4414, 0, 7347, 2580, 27309, 1502, 7518, 
1681, 3905, 10728, 6090, 7918, 5326, 3961, 6340, 10684, 6448, 
36141, 17583, 2430, 2473, 4684, 12889, 41084, 16638, 6535, 969, 
15818, 9260), `2014` = c(0, 4367, 0, 6346, 2209, 31058, 1720, 
7881, 1850, 5661, 14518, 6624, 10580, 5920, 4441, 6648, 11421, 
7070, 47139, 21731, 2607, 2295, 4921, 13610, 50464, 17915, 6599, 
972, 14611, 10414), `2015` = c(0, 4776, 0, 4921, 2606, 35003, 
1890, 8601, 1780, 5157, 15002, 6797, 10865, 6057, 5158, 7244, 
12818, 7217, 50349, 22886, 2924, 2354, 4893, 14240, 50223, 19992, 
6800, 913, 15571, 11804), `2016` = c(0, 3822, 0, 4858, 2102, 
37319, 2022, 9592, 1871, 5742, 15526, 9216, 10579, 5864, 5419, 
8239, 13446, 8808, 53770, 23388, 3052, 1965, 4533, 14555, 51787, 
20728, 6116, 1124, 16783, 12900), `2017` = c(0, 4231, 0, 7002, 
2506, 41952, 2295, 10938, 2117, 6115, 16304, 8685, 10980, 6003, 
6808, 9077, 14351, 8411, 58195, 26806, 3469, 2080, 4966, 17092, 
53900, 20718, 7553, 1324, 18283, 12907), `2018` = c(0, 4231, 
0, 7002, 2506, 41952, 2295, 10938, 2117, 6115, 16304, 8685, 10980, 
6003, 6808, 9077, 14351, 8411, 58195, 26806, 3469, 2080, 4966, 
17092, 53900, 20718, 7553, 1324, 18283, 12907), `2019` = c(0, 
4231, 0, 7002, 2506, 41952, 2295, 10938, 2117, 6115, 16304, 8685, 
10980, 6003, 6808, 9077, 14351, 8411, 58195, 26806, 3469, 2080, 
4966, 17092, 53900, 20718, 7553, 1324, 18283, 12907), `2020` = c(0, 
4231, 0, 7002, 2506, 41952, 2295, 10938, 2117, 6115, 16304, 8685, 
10980, 6003, 6808, 9077, 14351, 8411, 58195, 26806, 3469, 2080, 
4966, 17092, 53900, 20718, 7553, 1324, 18283, 12907), `2021` = c(0, 
4231, 0, 7002, 2506, 41952, 2295, 10938, 2117, 6115, 16304, 8685, 
10980, 6003, 6808, 9077, 14351, 8411, 58195, 26806, 3469, 2080, 
4966, 17092, 53900, 20718, 7553, 1324, 18283, 12907)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`1` = 1L), class = "omit"))
```

Para os itens do primeiro grupo (Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás), respectivamente, carvão mineral, minerais não-metálicos, minério de ferro e minerais metálicos não-ferrosos, eu precisaria, para 2010, encontrar os seguintes valores: 0.0, 0.344, 0.517 e 0.139.

A ideia geral é encontrar esses valores percentuais para todos os anos.

Códito que utilizei:

```
library(tidyverse)

variaveis <- c("Carvão mineral", "Minerais não-metálicos", "Minério de ferro", "Minerais metálicos não-ferrosos")

dados %>%
    group_by(item, atividade) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(variaveis), funs(. / sum(.)))
```

Comment: Alexandre, Boa noite! O valor de carvão mineral em 2010 é zero, ele realmente representa 0.141?

Comment: Perdão pelo erro, já corrigi os valores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma possível solução seria pivotar o data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados2 <- pivot_longer(
  data = dados,
  cols = starts_with('20'),
  names_to = 'Ano',
  values_to = 'Valores'
)
```

Depois agrupamos e calculamos a porcentagem:

```
teste <-  dados2 %>% group_by(Ano, Atividade) %>%
  mutate('%' = Valores/sum(Valores) * 100)
```

Como geramos alguns NA, temos que remover:

```
teste[is.na(teste)] = 0
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Por nada Alexandre! Abraço!

Answer (score 3):

Aqui está uma solução relativamente simples.

```
library(dplyr)

variaveis <- c("Carvão mineral", "Minerais não-metálicos", "Minério de ferro", "Minerais metálicos não-ferrosos")

dados %>%
  filter(Item %in% variaveis) %>%
  group_by(Atividade) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(`2010`:`2021`), ~./sum(.)) %>%
  bind_cols(Item = dados %>% filter(Item %in% variaveis) %>% pull(Item), .)
## A tibble: 4 x 14
#  Item             Atividade         `2010` `2011` `2012` `2013` `2014` `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019` `2020` `2021`
#  <chr>            <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 Carvão mineral   Extrativas ex-pe…  0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0    
#2 Minerais não-me… Extrativas ex-pe…  0.344  0.327  0.306  0.308  0.338  0.388  0.354  0.308  0.308  0.308  0.308  0.308
#3 Minério de ferro Extrativas ex-pe…  0.517  0.524  0.509  0.512  0.491  0.400  0.451  0.510  0.510  0.510  0.510  0.510
#4 Minerais metáli… Extrativas ex-pe…  0.139  0.149  0.184  0.180  0.171  0.212  0.195  0.182  0.182  0.182  0.182  0.182
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela solução.

Answer (score 3):

A pergunta está com a tag `dplyr`, mas para ficar registrado, eis como calcular as porcentagens por grupo para todas as colunas numéricas usando `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dados)

percentage <- function(x) nafill(x/sum(x), fill = 0)  # função para calcular porcentagem e trocar NA/NaN por 0

cols <- names(dados)[sapply(dados, is.numeric)]  # nomes das colunas numéricas

dados.pct <- copy(dados)  # caso queira preservar os dados originais

dados.pct[, paste(cols) := lapply(.SD, percentage), by = Atividade, .SDcols = cols]


> dados.pct[Atividade == "Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás", 1:4]
                              Item                    Atividade      2010      2011
1:                  Carvão mineral Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás 0.0000000 0.0000000
2:          Minerais não-metálicos Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás 0.3440471 0.3271726
3:                Minério de ferro Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás 0.5165233 0.5239545
4: Minerais metálicos não-ferrosos Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás 0.1394296 0.1488729
```

Alternativamente, se quiser criar novas colunas no data.frame original, basta atribuir novos nomes:

```
dados[, paste0(cols,"pctAtv") := lapply(.SD, percentage), by = Atividade, .SDcols = cols]


> dados[Atividade == "Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás", c(1:4,15:16)]
                              Item                    Atividade 2010 2011 2010pctAtv 2011pctAtv
1:                  Carvão mineral Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás    0    0  0.0000000  0.0000000
2:          Minerais não-metálicos Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás 3800 4514  0.3440471  0.3271726
3:                Minério de ferro Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás 5705 7229  0.5165233  0.5239545
4: Minerais metálicos não-ferrosos Extrativas ex-petróleo e gás 1540 2054  0.1394296  0.1488729
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa informar os nomes das colunas para o `mutate_at`. Além disso, deve agrupar apenas por Atividade (ou o total para o cálculo da porcentagem será dado por cada ítem de cada atividade).

```
library(dplyr)

variaveis <- names(dados)[sapply(dados, is.numeric)] # todas as colunas numéricas
## ou
variaveis <- grep("^20", names(dados), value = TRUE) # todas as colunas que começam com "20"

dados %>%
    group_by(Atividade) %>%
    mutate_at(variaveis, .funs = list(~ coalesce(./sum(.), 0)))  # coalesce para substituir NaNs/NAs
```